# Print a range of lines from a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file (the U.S. constitution) and I want to print just the preamble. Here's the code I have so far:

```
lines = []
with open('Constitution.txt') as fhand:
    for line in fhand:
        lines.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
        print(lines[4:10])
        break
```

If, on the 5th line of code I type`print(lines[0])`, it works, and prints just the first line of the text, which is simply the word "THE". But I want it to print lines 5-11, which is the preamble, but it always comes back saying the index is out of range... How can I fix this?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Please provide a [mcve]... is `print(lines[...])` **inside** the loop?

Comment: OK. So, it would be useful if you think about *why* you are breaking out fo your loop. Is it necessary? Does it cause any problems? Why do you expect  there to be more than one line on your first iteration of the loop?

Comment: Read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to know the difference between read() and readlines()

Answer (score 3):

Make sure everything is at the right indentation level and that the print statement isn't inside the for loop.

You can also reduce it down with list comprehension to make it clearer.

```
with open('Constitution.txt') as fhand:
    lines = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in fhand]
print(lines[4:10])
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing `print(lines[4:10])` inside the loop. So the first line is added to the `lines` and then you print 4th to 10th of it - it only yet contains 1 line.

Move it outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the issue with your code is that you try to `print` lines from 5 to 11 before you form the list. To clarify, in your posted code when `print(lines[4:10])` is executed your `lines` list looks like `["THE"]`. Thus, the interpreter correctly says that you specified index which is out of range since the list only contains 1 item.

You should change your code like that:

```
lines = []
with open('Constitution.txt') as fhand:
    for line in fhand:
        lines.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
print(lines[4:10])
```

By the way, if the intention of your `break` statement was to terminate reading of the file after you read the first 11 lines, that is not what you did. Your `break` statement will be executed in the end of reading the first line.

Comment: You should post this as comment. Please use the "Your Answer" form to only verified answer.

Comment: While this is good advice, this shouldn't have been posted as an answer, but rather, as a comment.

Comment: @Joao Sorry, I could not comment due to low reputation. That's awkward.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17895857)

Comment: @maRtin Ok, I will no longer post such comments as an answer. I changed the original post to an answer though as soon as the author clarified the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the readlines() method to generate a list of lines from the file. Then you can use join() to print out the specific lines you are looking for.

```
with open('Constitution.txt') as fhand:
     print "".join(fhand.readlines()[4:10])
```

All that the "".join() bit does is take list elements 4 through 10 from your newly formed list and join them together end-to-end. Since your list elements already have a newline character, there is no need to join them with a newline. Take a look at your list to see what I mean.

```
with open('Constitution.txt') as fhand:
    print fhand.readlines()[4:10]

> ['line5\n', 'line6\n', 'line7\n', 'line8\n', 'line9\n', 'line10\n']
```